# aapt: res/layout/MainActivity.java Invalid file name

Tags: java, android, aide-ide

I use AIDE to compile android applications from inside Android. Usually, I copy the MainActivity.java to the computer, I edit it and then I copy it again to the mobile phone. Then, I run AIDE to compile the project. At this moment, I have this error :

`aapt: res/layout/MainActivity.java          Invalid file name:must contain only [a-z0-9_.]`

I don't know what is happening. The name is correct `MainActivity.java.`

Any idea ?

Comment: Put the file into your `java` folder not the resources.

Comment: MainActivity.java will ne in src/package/MainActivity.java and res/layout/MainActivity.java will contain res/layout/mainactivity.xml

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Your .java files should be in a package in the src folder not in the res/layout folder, res/layout is for .xml layout files and can only have names with lowercase letters and numbers after the first letter.

Answer (score 1):

**src**
Source Code this is where the Java source code is placed. The Java files are organised into packages that directly map to the folder structure (i.e. the package apc.examples impels a folder structure examples)

**gen**
Android tools generate code to map resources into the Java code. This generated code is placed in this folder.

**Android 2.2**
The Android framework library is stored here.

**assets**
Project specific assets are placed here. Developers often store application data files that do not need to change here.

**res**
This is the location to store resources used in the application. Specifically images layouts and strings.

[image]

for more see this [official document](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to Store Java file inside in the package of your project not in the res folder.

`res Folder` contains only resources of project. Move your file to package folder.

See this Links will give you more idea.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Put `java` file in your Package Folder. i.e. src/.
`res/layout` is for `xml` file which is design part of your android app.

Answer (score 0):

*Or Just Rename it.*
*From:*

```
MainActivity.java
```

*Into:*

```
mainactivity.xml
```

> But it should be a xml placed in layouts folder else move it into the src/java folder